# Lights not work, but each wire seems to have 120v

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, multiway-switch

I have a 3 way switch but the lights went out on all associated lights.

I went around and tested each light. For each light black & ground together and got 120v. I then tested white/red and ground and equally got 120v. However, when I test white/red and black together, I get 0.4v.

When I turn the switch off, that 0.4 turns to 0.00 so it seems the switch works.

Would love any help thank you!

Comment: I doubt anyone can understand what it means to "test white/red and black together".  Please clarify what you did.  Also please tell us if you're in the USA?  Do you actually have 4 wires attached to each light???

Comment: Sorry! Yes I am in the US and yes 4 wires but a single live and neutral wire to each light. I used the voltameter to test voltage. When I use the voltemeter and hold live and ground I get a full circle at 120v. But when I hold the neutral wire and ground for the loop I also get 120v

Comment: the white is a hot wire on purpose

Comment: two things:  What changed? Did the 3 way switches suddenly stop working, or did you do something like try to install a smart switch? 

Also, to @knowitall  The white in a fixture box is only marked as hot if the fixture is on a switch leg.    Whenever I wire a house, it's hot to the switch box, then hot to the next switch box, each fixture box is fed from the switch box, no re-marking wires needed and supports future smart switches bc they need a neutral that's not available in a switch leg. Regarding 3-way switches...continued in next comment....

Comment: If at all possible I run power to the first 3-way switch, then the travelers to the other 3-way switch and from the second 3-way to the fixture(s), no remarking needed and again, will future proof the installation for smart switches.   I NEVER use switch leg circuits. So politely commenting to Mr. Knowitall,, I don't think you do.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments above, each of the lights measures 120 VAC hot-to-ground, and 120 VAC neutral-to-ground.  We can infer the 0.4 VAC measurement was hot-to-neutral.

In the most simple terms, this means the neutral wire going to the lights is connected to the hot wire going to the lights.  Because the same measurement was found at each light and because the circuit is otherwise working, it would seem there is not a short circuit nor panelboard issue, but a bad junction at or near one of the switches.

If you have only hot, neutral, and ground going to each light, they should be black, white, and bare copper.  So I don't know why you mentioned "red" twice in the original post.

The first step in troubleshooting should be to turn off the circuit breaker and verify all of the hot and neutral wires at the lights are then 0 VAC to ground.

The second step should be to look behind the switches and check for any black wire touching any white wire.  Also look for any white wire touching any switch.  This might or might not reveal the problem.

Comment: ` So I don't know why you mentioned "red" twice in the original post.` Because it's a 3-way switch and red is the next color used by cable manufacturers when they make a /3 cable. The red & black are used as travelers between 3-way switches.

Comment: Red and black travellers as switched hots: That's the US convention I'm familiar with. May be different elsewhere. (And I am not a pro electrician, so it's possible I'm missing something. Just got caught in a goof in another question.)